# InDesign: Keyboard shortcut for "Remove Selected Local Overrides"?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I use <kbd>Remove Selected Local Overrides</kbd> a lot, but each use requires fine mouse movements and at least four clicks.

[image: Remove Selected Local Overrides is buried]

I've tried speeding this up by using *Quick Apply* and custom keyboard shortcuts, but this action doesn't appear in either menu. It's not where it should be in <kbd>Edit > Menus…</kbd>, and its entire submenu appears to be missing from *Quick Apply*.

[image: Remove Selected Local Overrides doesn't appear in menu customization]

I suspect the problem may have something to do with <kbd>Remove Selected Local Overrides</kbd> transforming into <kbd>Remove All Local Overrides</kbd> when there's not an applicable object selected.

How can I <kbd>Remove Selected Local Overrides</kbd> with fewer clicks—and ideally the keyboard only?

Answer (score 1):

*Remove Selected Local Overrides* is available in *Quick Apply* (<kbd>⌘⎵</kbd>), but you need to <kbd>Show Hidden Keyboard Commands</kbd> in the *Quick Apply* options, which isn't toggled on by default.

[image: Quick Apply options]

Click on the downward triangle ▼ to reveal *Quick Apply* options. Voila!

[image: Quick Apply has Remove Selected Local Overrides]

You may need to be careful of how you spell “Remove Selected Local Overrides”; it didn't work for me after the first few tries. And I have no idea how Adobe came to their definition of “hidden”.